# bivariate inter- and extrapolation to create heatmap that fills up a circle

Tags: r, heatmap, smoothing

I have several points within a unit circle in 2D. The points (red, green) come from one of two classes.

```
library(plotrix)

# draw points within circle
n <- 100
d <- data.frame(x= rnorm(n), 
                y= rnorm(n))
d <- d[sqrt(d$x^2 + d$y^2) < 1, ] 
d$value <- ifelse(d$x > 0, 2, 3)
plot(d$x, d$y, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), pch=16, asp=1, col=d$value)
draw.circle(0,0,1)
```

[image]

Now I want to overlay the plot with smooth heatmap indicating the region for each group.

```
library(akima)
library(scales)

# estimate surface
nxy <- 100
xyo <- seq(-1, 1, len=nxy)
int <- interp(x = d$x, y = d$y, z = d$value, 
                      extrap = T, 
                      xo = xyo, yo = xyo, 
                      nx = nxy, ny=nxy, 
                      linear = T)
colors <- alpha(colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(40) , .4)
image(xyo, xyo, int$z, add = T, col = colors)
```

[image]

So far so good. My problem is to find a way to extrapolate the heatmap to the edges of the circle, so it fills up the whole circle. There is an argument `extrap`. In the docs it says: `logical flag: should extrapolation be used outside of the convex hull determined by the data points?`. I set it to `TRUE`, however, this does not seem to work.

**Any ideas how to estimate a smooth surface that covers the whole circle?**

Comment: `packageVersion("akima")`?

Comment: `akima` Version 0.6-2

Comment: Okay, I found the reason in the details: `No extrapolation can be performed for the linear case.` Well, better RTFM :)

Answer (score 0):

After understanding that extrapolation requires `linear=FALSE`, the solution is straighforward. First we can draw the extrapolated values for the whole rectangle.

```
library(akima)
library(plotrix)
library(scales)

plot(d$x, d$y, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), pch=16, asp=1, col=d$value)
draw.circle(0,0,1)

# estimate surface
nxy <- 100
xyo <- seq(-1, 1, len=nxy)
int <- interp(x = d$x, y = d$y, z = d$value, 
                      extrap = T, 
                      xo = xyo, yo = xyo, 
                      nx = nxy, ny=nxy, 
                      linear = F)
z <- int$z

# extrapolation with tweaking of color breaks
colors <- alpha(colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(21), .4)
br <- seq(2.3, 2.7, len=20)
image(xyo, xyo, z, add = T, col = colors, breaks=c(0, br, 5))
```

[image]

In a last step, the pixels outside the circle must be removed to get the final plot.

```
plot(d$x, d$y, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), pch=16, asp=1, col=d$value)
draw.circle(0,0,1)

# remove values outside circle
inside <- outer(xyo, xyo, FUN = function(x,y) sqrt(x^2 + y^2) < 1)
z[!inside] <- NA
plot(d$x, d$y, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), pch=16, asp=1, col=d$value)
draw.circle(0,0,1)
colors <- alpha(colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(21), .4)
br <- seq(2.3, 2.7, len=20)
image(xyo, xyo, z, add = T, col = colors, breaks=c(0, br, 5))
```

[image]